# Plesk 10 Postfix with multiple IP adresses and SSL certificates

Tags: postfix, ip-address, tls

We are currently running a root server with Debian 6 and Plesk 10.4.4. We have some virtual hosts using one IP adress (shared) - e.g. example1.com - and another virtual host using a dedicated IP address (example2.com).

Is there a way to configure postfix to do the following

1. Always use the IP address of the virtual host to which the e-mail account belongs (so that an e-mail from example@example1.com will originate from the shared IP-Address and an e-mail from example@example2.com will originate from the dedicated IP?
2. Use different certificates for TLS for example1.com and example2.com?

If the latter is not possible: Could any problems arrive when using example1.com as certificate for example2.com users? Of course, example2.com users would have to configure their clients to use example1.com as the SMTP server name to avoid annoying security warnings. But if we still would be able to get the effect of the first point that would  still be acceptable.

Comment: No, you are not running "root server". Well, I hope so. http://bit.ly/HIi5ph (lmgtfy, see first result)

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

As of #1 - this should be default behavior of Plesk if you are on Postfix mail server:

*[+] (Only for Linux) Outgoing e-mails from a customer's exclusive IP. Outgoing e-mails are sent from a dedicated IP address owned by a customer, thus reducing the risk of blacklisting the whole server for spam. Subscriptions hosted on a single shared IP address will use this shared address for outgoing e-mail (instead of using the IP address occupied by Panel). The feature requires Postfix 2.7+ and is supported on the following operating systems:...*

[see more here](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.4/release-notes/parallels-plesk-panel-10.4-for-linux-based-os.html)